Not setting viewport causes long lines to have larger font size on mobile devices
I have this piece of code below:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>This is not so long a piece of text.</div>
    </body>
</html>

I display in Google Chrome's mobile emulator and things work just fine. Then I modified the content of the div:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long piece of text.</div>
    </body>
</html>

And all of a sudden the font becomes extra large. What is even stranger is that the computed font size of the div is now not the default 16px, but 41.791px when I am using the iPhone SE emulator (375 * 667).
The problem is solved if I set viewport in <head>. However, I am at a loss as to why this is happening if I do not set viewport. I understand that viewport has something to do with shrinking the content size to fit the screen of a mobile device, but how come I get different font sizes with lines of different length?

It might be a good time to read into the following topics: "difference between hardware and software pixels" as well as DPR (Device Pixel Ratio). Hardware and Softwarepixels are not the same!

@tacoshy With due respect, I do not think this answers the question. My problem is not with the difference between 16px and 41.791px, which I suspect is how you come to offer the suggestion of reading about hardware and software pixels. My question is: how come two pieces of similar code, with a mere change in content, results in different font sizes on the same device, presumably with the same hardware and software.

it was not posted as an answer but as a comment, as I had (and still have)  the feeling that you do not know the difference of them. It is not meant as a solution for the problem you face but to understand what party is happening and what setting "viewport"  actually does.

Well, my understanding of the viewport is that, without it, the browser renders a page with a fixed size and then tries to fit the virtual page into the smaller screen. With viewport set, it sets the width of the page according to the screen width. This would explain why the first piece of code results in smaller fonts, which is expected, but not, as far as I can see, why the second piece yields a larger font.

No, the viewport line disables the DPR function.

Have you read the explanation given under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag yet?

I copied your code exactly but was unable to reproduce your results. The text is the same size (16px) in both cases. Suggest you test again. If you are still getting the same result, record a screenshot video with commentary which demonstrates what you are doing to see these different results, then upload it to YouTube and post a link to it here.

@BrettDonald I cannot access youtube so I have uploaded the video on veed: https://www.veed.io/view/a26252b7-1a3c-4ada-8b82-cbbc1e677621?panel=share

The video shows the opposite of what is stated in your question. The video shows the shorter piece of text being displayed at a smaller size, and the longer piece of text being displayed at a larger size.

What? My question states that with a longer line the font size is larger, same as the vid shows @BrettDonald
"And all of a sudden the font becomes extra large" is what I said

Apologies, I was wrong. But I still can’t reproduce what you are seeing.

Figured it out eventually. This is actually quite an interesting css feature I have never before laid eyes on. See here:

Since text that has been scaled down to fit a mobile screen may be very small, many mobile browsers apply a text inflation algorithm to enlarge the text to make it more readable. When an element containing text uses 100% of the screen's width, the algorithm increases its text size, but without modifying the layout. The text-size-adjust property allows web authors to disable or modify this behavior, as web pages designed with small screens in mind do not need it.

Also, see here:

Chrome (v40) has an emulator "feature" described thus:
Autosizes (boosts) text for pages without a defined viewport.

The solution, should I choose not use a viewport meta tag, is to set this in style:
html {
    text-size-adjust: none;
}

